# Setting up Hadoop in a public cloud

Tags: hadoop, cloud

As a part of my college project, I would like to modify Hadoop's source code. However, the problem is that I would need atleast 20 systems to test it. Is it possible to setup this modified version of Hadoop in public clouds such as Google Cloud platform or Amazon Services?Can you give me an idea on the procedure to follow?I could only find information about setting up the original Hadoop versions in the public cloud set up. I couldn't find any information that is relevant to my case.Please do help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon offers elastic mapreduce. But as you correctly pointed out you will not be able to deploy your version of hadoop there.

But you still can use Amazon or Google cloud to just get the base linux servers and install your hadoop on it. It is just a longer process but not different from any other hadoop installation if you have done it before.